# Replace some textr with sed

Tags: linux, image, text, sed, editor

Can you please help me. I have some line of almost repeatebel text , and i need to insert
before smashdocs/backend/sd9934  *manifests/* text.

I try to use
'/sd/i manifests ' smashdocs/backend/sd9934 But it doesn't work.

Old veriosn - smashdocs/backend/sd9934
New version -smashdocs/backend/manifests/sd9934

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use insert but only replace (`s`):

```
sed -e's#smashdocs/backend/sd9934#smashdocs/backend/manifests/sd9934#g'
```

Replace characters by regexp as needed.

Comment: but i have multiple line 
smashdocs/backend/sd9934
smashdocs/backend/sd12830
smashdocs/backend/sd12940
smashdocs/backend/sdox-template-1
smashdocs/backend/sd12927
smashdocs/backend/sd12523
smashdocs/backend/sd13071
smashdocs/backend/sd12944
smashdocs/backend/sd12945
smashdocs/backend/sd12938
smashdocs/backend/sd12946
smashdocs/backend/sd12803
smashdocs/backend/sd12891
smashdocs/backend/sd12951

Comment: That's what I meant be "use regexp as needed". `sed -e's#smashdocs/backend/\(sd[0-9]*\)#smashdocs/backend/manifests/\1#g'`. Or simply leave away the numbers and only search `smashdocs/backend/sd` and replace with `smashdocs/backend/manifest/sd`

Comment: how it simple comand will be looks like, i try 
sed -e's#smashdocs/backend/sd#smashdocs/backend/manifests/g' list_input.txt
buit it doesn't work

Comment: in list_input.txt i save the line like i published before

Comment: If you want to change the file "in-place", add `-i` (or `-i.bkp`) flag to sed, e.g. `sed -i.bkp -e's#smashdocs/backend/sd#smashdocs/backend/manifest/sd#g' list_input.txt`